# Can I get some help with this integral? $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{x\sin^{100}(x)}{\cos^{100}(x)+\sin^{100}(x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

(I'm still trying to understand this concept) I tried to separate the integral, as $cos(x)\geq sin(x)$ in $[0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ and $[\frac{5\pi}{4},2\pi]$, therefore $\sin^{100}(x)$ goes to $0$ faster than $\cos^{100}(x)$ does. 
Like this, $\dfrac{sin^{100}(x)}{\cos^{100}(x)+\sin^{100}(x)} \to{0}$ so the integral will be $0$.
On the other hand, in $[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{5\pi}{4}]$ this $\dfrac{sin^{100}(x)}{\cos^{100}(x)+\sin^{100}(x)}\to{1}$ so the integral will be $\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}x dx$. Like this, I will get $\frac{25\pi^{2}}{32} - \frac{\pi^{2}}{32} = \frac{24\pi^{2}}{32} = \frac{3\pi^{2}}{4}$ which is not the answer...

Comment: Are you trying to find the exact value of the integral, or just some approximation?  If you are trying to find an approximation you're on the right track, although you really need to consider when $|cos(x)| > |sin(x)|$, with the absolute value.

Comment: "goes faster to zero" is how you'd approach limits. But there's no limit shown.

Comment: @elisa According to your method, i can also get$\pi^2$ as an answer..i think the question asks to find exact value of integral

Comment: I tried to generalize it as that 100 is a big number, that's why I treated it like it was a limit. And can you explain further the suggestion with absolute value? I need the exact value, but I know no other way to solve this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2161411/evaluating-some-integrals

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{x\sin^{100}(x)}{\cos^{100}(x)+\sin^{100}(x)}dx$$
Now, make the substitution $x=2\pi-u$ to get $$\begin{align}I&=-\int_{2\pi}^{0}\dfrac{(2\pi-u)\sin^{100}(2\pi-u)}{\cos^{100}(2\pi-u)+\sin^{100}(2\pi-u)}du\\&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{(2\pi-u)\sin^{100}(u)}{\cos^{100}(u)+\sin^{100}(u)}du\\&=-I+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{2\pi\sin^{100}(u)}{\cos^{100}(u)+\sin^{100}(u)}du\\\implies I&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\dfrac{\pi\sin^{100}(u)}{\cos^{100}(u)+\sin^{100}(u)}du\\&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{2\pi\sin^{100}(u)}{\cos^{100}(u)+\sin^{100}(u)}du\\&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{4\pi\sin^{100}(u)}{\cos^{100}(u)+\sin^{100}(u)}du\end{align}$$
Where we made use of the periodicity. Now, use the fact that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\cos(x)$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)=\sin(x)$ and use the substitution $u=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$ to get $$I=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0}\dfrac{4\pi\sin^{100}(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)}{\cos^{100}(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)+\sin^{100}(\frac{\pi}{2}-t)}dt=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{4\pi\cos^{100}(t)}{\cos^{100}(t)+\sin^{100}(t)}dt$$
Now, add these two $I$'s together: $$I+I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\dfrac{4\pi\cos^{100}(t)+4\pi\sin^{100}(t)}{\cos^{100}(t)+\sin^{100}(t)}dt=4\pi\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=2\pi^2\implies \boxed{I=\pi^2}$$

Comment: $I=\pi^2$ (you forgot the square just at the end).

Comment: $4\pi \cdot \pi/2 = 2\pi^2$ in the last line, so we get $I = \pi^2$.

Comment: I think you want $I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{x\sin^{100}(x)}{\cos^{100}(x)+\sin^{100}(x)}\ dx$ :P

Comment: Yeah, I made a few typos. Was just about to fix, but you guys are too fast. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it!!  +1. :)

Answer (score 4):

Let the integral be $I$ Using $f (x)=f (2\pi-x)$ and remembering $\sin (2\pi-x)=-\cos (x) $ we see that the cos cancel from numerator and denominator. Thus $I=\int _0 ^{2\pi} (\pi-\frac {x}{2}) =\pi ^2$

Answer (score 2):

Here are some hints as to how to get the exactly answer $\pi^2$

1. Do the substitution $u=2\pi-x$. This has the effect of removing the spare $x$ term from the integrand. You get $2I=2\pi\int_0^{2\pi}...$
2. Consider symmetry and do $4\times \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}...$
3. Finally do another substitution $x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$ and consider $$I+I=4\pi\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1d\theta$$

I hope this helps and you would like to try it for yourself